# How is the structure of the different structural classes of exocrine glands relate to their functions?

Tags: health-education, cells, laboratory

Specifically speaking, how would the structures of simple tubular, branched tubular, coiled tubular, simple acinar, branched acing, compound tubular, compound acinar, tubuloacinar relate to each of their respective functions? Like I can easily memorise for example that sebaceous glands are branched acinar, but why so? what makes this structural class the most appropriate for its function? Please help me understand the importance of having different structural classes.

Edit: I am a first year medical student taking histology for the first time, my primary resource is [Junqueira's Basic Histology](https://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/book.aspx?bookID=3047#). I googled the relationship between the structural class of each gland and its function, but haven't found any answers.